# Axios post with Google Service Account OAUTH2

Tags: node.js, authentication, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I was wondering how to implement a google authentication when sending a post request in NodeJs to a Google Python App. I cannot seem to find a direct solution anywhere. I have the `.json` file in my Node project. My request looks like this:

```
let options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: mainUrl,
  data: payload,
  authentication: auth,
    //auth = const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: "PathToMyJson.json",
  scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"],

}
axios
  .request(mainUrl, options)

  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status)
    console.log(response.data)
  })

  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error.response)
    console.trace(error)
  })
```

I am not sure if this is the right approach, however.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using App Engine to provision your app? Have you considered using Identity-aware Proxy? This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/authenticate-users) might be helpful for you.

Comment: The app is a Python flask app, deployed on Google App Engine. I'll check out the document, thank you :)